# Using KeyboardEvent to navigate through scenes in Flash AS 3.0 without inherited script

Tags: flash-cs6, scene

I am making a simple animation made up of 5 looping scenes.  I want to use certain keyboardEvents to procede to the next scene.  So far I have put the following code in Scene 2;

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, plutofl_KeyboardDownHandler);

function plutofl_KeyboardDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
  if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.Q) {
    gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 3"); 
  }   else if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.W) {
    gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 1"); 
  }
}
```

The animation advances up scenes fine but to go back it inherits the action from the scene it has just left and gets stuck.  Is there a simple way to keep the action script for only the current scene?